# Insertion of a non-english string to database

Tags: posts

How can i insert a non-english string (like persian) to a tabale in Wordpress database? When i insert the persian string, It shows with `"??????"` character in the table? This is the code:

-Creating table:

```
function fjn_add_polls_table_to_db(){
    global $wpdb;
    $polls_table = $wpdb->prefix. 'polls';
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$polls_table}'" ) != $polls_table ){
        $query =
            "CREATE TABLE {$polls_table} (
            poll_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            title VARCHAR(128),
            author_id TINYINT(4) ,
            all_votes BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0
            );";
        require_once( ABSPATH. 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $query );
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'fjn_add_polls_table_to_db');
```

-Insertion:

```
function add_records_to_db(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $pid=get_the_ID();
    $ptitle=get_the_title();
    $aid=$post->post_author;
    $wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_polls', 
    array( 
        'poll_id' => $pid , 
        'title' => $ptitle,
        'author_id' => $aid,
        'all_votes' => "",
    ), 
    array( 
        '%d', 
        '%s',
        '%d',
        '%d'
    ) 
);
}
add_action( 'publish_poll', 'add_records_to_db');
```

Note that `$ptitle` is a non English string.

Comment: Have you tried `$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();` and then use it in the SQL query ? `...all_votes BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0
            ) $charset_collate;`

Comment: Thanks @Samuel Elh . Now i'm trying to fetch the strings (non-latin) from database and then show them in homepage. But after that I see some strange strings like: Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… . What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

In most of case, it would bee easier to use a Custom Post Type instead of creating a new table
then it can solve you encoding problem because WordPress use unicode